# TV series or film: cartoon with narrator, faerie forest, castle with witches

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

It was a cartoon, and I saw it in VHS. I think it was several episodes of one TV series, but I am not sure. It may be a film or a special episode.

I remember that it has a narrator. That they travel through a portal or something magical. They went to a faerie forest, a castle with witches, and maybe some kind of aquatic world.

I saw it in the 90s.

Comment: I have already remembered. It was Where's Wally?: The Animated Series (1991)